# How to render javascript image [object HTMLImageElement] into dom using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi i want to display image with full size as per the actual size with a modal

**Note:** once the image is loaded then only i want to show the modal with image size(i,e `width,height` of image).

```
  let img = new Image();
  img.onload = this.imageLoaded(img);
  img.onerror = this.imageNotFound;
  img.src = this.imageUrl;
```

once the image is loaded then i will call `imageLoaded(params)` and set the modal width and height accordingly

```
   imageLoaded(img){
     this.imagePreviewObj.width = img.width;
     this.imagePreviewObj.height = img.height;
     this.imagePreviewObj.image = img;
     this.isPreviewReady = true;
   }

  <div class="modal" v-if="isPreviewReady" :style="{'width':imagePreviewObj.width+'px','height':imagePreviewObj.height+'px'}">
       <!-- append image here -->
   </div>
```

**Note:** i don't want browser to download image 2 times from server with the image `[object HTMLImageElement]` i want to complete my modal.

**Here is what i have tried:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data(){
       return {
           isPreviewReady:false,
           imagePreviewObj :{width:null,height:null,image:''},

           imageUrl:'http://placehold.jp/450x290.png',
       }
    },
    methods:{
       imageLoaded(img){
          console.log(img);
          this.imagePreviewObj.width = img.width;
          this.imagePreviewObj.height = img.height;
          this.imagePreviewObj.image = img;
          this.isPreviewReady = true;
       },
       imageNotFound(){
           alert('not found');
       },
       findImageWidthAndHeight(){
            let img = new Image();
            img.onload = this.imageLoaded(img);
            img.onerror = this.imageNotFound;
            img.src = this.imageUrl;
       }
   },
   created(){
      this.findImageWidthAndHeight();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">

<div class="modal" v-if="isPreviewReady" :style="{'width':imagePreviewObj.width+'px','height':imagePreviewObj.height+'px'}">
         <span v-html="imagePreviewObj.image"></span>
     </div>

</div>
```

**For better view codepen:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/zYEpWzd

Please help me thanks in advance !!!

Comment: `this.imageLoaded(img)` will call the function and assign the returned value to the callback, and not assign the function to the callback. Try `img.onload = this.imageLoaded` and handle the event passed in.

Comment: @StevenSpungin what i'm doing might be wrong, my final question is i want to see the image rendered in `DOM` with its actual `width` and `height`.

Comment: also i have tried in codepen for better experience https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/zYEpWzd

Comment: This is not neccessary. The browser will cache the image on its own if you use it more than once. Just use `<img :src="imageUrl" alt="">` and it's fine.